# Drush - module/feature changes -- dev --> qa --> staging --> prod

Tags: distributions, drush

Is Drush make file and install profile used for the initial set up only? We are in very early stages of development and trying to figure out the best approaches to transfer changes across environments: dev --> qa --> staging --> prod

Say that week 1, I created an install profile and used that to set up the distribution in qa environment. In week 2, I added a few more modules. How do I go about adding the new modules in qa environment? Looks like "drush make filename.make" is used for creating new site, but not updating.

Comment: Sounds like the Features module is what you are looking for. It's far from perfect but it's the only way I know of to encapsulate related configuration settings (apart from hacking them into code by hand).